# Spree: Change image location relatively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have my assets stored in Amazon s3 bucket but for development mode I have stored the images under

```
app/assets/images/spree/products/
```

folder. The images are not loaded on server rendering as the url in spree views evaluate to 
   /spree/products/1/small/vanillabreeze00.jpg?1375747478"

and I want to change it to /assets/spree/products/1/small/vanillabreeze00.jpg?1375747478
 because that's where the image is present.

I am using :

```
gem 'spree', :github=> 'spree/spree', :branch=> '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch=> '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch=> '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_variant_options', :git => 'git://github.com/ScienceInc/spree_variant_options.git', :branch => 'spree2'
```

Comment: The URL evaluated by spree will go to assets/images/spree/products/1/small/vanillabreeze00.jpg. Is there any chance you can move it there?

Comment: @techvineet It is indeed present there. http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/spree/products/1/small/vanillabreeze00.jpg show the image. Spree calls a relative generated url which generate the link as /spree/products/1/small/vanillabreeze00.jpg. I need to add /assets in the beginning.

Comment: You don't need to add assets, images are by default searched in /assets/images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree image location functionality is provided by the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

It is configured within Spree::Image here:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.4/core/app/models/spree/image.rb#L11-12

Those two lines list:

1. URL - The URL to fetch the images from your webserver
2. Path - The file system path where the image is stored

You can customize these using these config values:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.4/core/app/models/spree/image.rb#L23-24

so in your case, you could set:

```
Spree::Config[:attachment_url] = '/assets/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

That being said.  I would **recommend against doing this**.

Things stored under /app in Rails should be under version control.  Since these images can be uploaded (to create new ones), deleted, modified, etc.  That would change those images, forcing you to update the images stored in version control all the time.

I would recommend following the standard Spree configuration and instead moving your images from

> app/assets/images/spree/products/

to

> public/spree/products

You can safely ignore all files under public/spree from your version control system, and everything should work out great!

Answer (score 1):

The following combination finally worked for me with the latest Spree (2-3-stable). Replace the `S3.yml` placeholders with your actual S3 credentials. I used the 'fog' and 'paperclip' gems together.

#### Gemfile

```
ruby '2.1.0'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'pg'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'money', '5.1.1'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'highline', '1.6.21'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'fog'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do

  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: 'master'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'spree_paypal_express', :github => "radar/better_spree_paypal_express", :branch => "master"
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree/spree_static_content', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree/spree_i18n', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_chimpy', github: 'DynamoMTL/spree_chimpy', branch: 'master'
```

#### /config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:url] = ':path'
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:path] = 'spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

#### /config/s3.yml

```
development:
  bucket: "BUCKET_NAME"
  access_key_id: "ACCESS_ID"
  secret_access_key: "SECRET_KEY"

test:
  bucket: "BUCKET_NAME"
  access_key_id: "ACCESS_ID"
  secret_access_key: "SECRET_KEY"

production:
  bucket: "BUCKET_NAME"
  access_key_id: "ACCESS_ID"
  secret_access_key: "SECRET_KEY"
```

#### /config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")[Rails.env]
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => S3_CONFIG['access_key_id'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key'],
    :region => 'us-west-2'
  },
  :fog_directory => S3_CONFIG['bucket'], 
  :bucket => S3_CONFIG['bucket'],
)
```

#### /models/spree/image_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Image.class_eval do
  attachment_definitions[:attachment][:styles] = {
    :mini => '48x48>', # thumbs under image
    :small => '350x700>', # images on category view
    :product => '1024x768>', # full product image
    :large => '600x600>' # light box image
  }
end
```